# C or Obj-c function to normalize range to x-y

Tags: objective-c, c, math, range, interpolation

I have an output of ranges from 150-0.  I want to map those to 0 to 1.  Or perhaps 0 to (some value less than 1 such as 0.5) where 150 is 0 and 0 is 1 ( or some values less than..).

Is this considered interpolation?  What is the formula to derive these values?  But preferably, is there a built-in StdLib function I can call?

Comment: Try to write that and add the code to the question.

Comment: Yes, this is linear interpolation. No, there is no built-in function that does this. The formula you want is the equation of a line given two points. The two points are `{150, 0}` and `{0, 1}`. With those two points it's simple algebra to find the equation in the form `y = mx + b`, that maps the input values to the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide your number by the (Max - min). This would make 150 be 1 and 0 will be 0, with everything else a number in between. Now, to make it the opposite just do 1 - result.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to map 0-1 to any custom range, you need to multiply range with `MAX-MIN` and then add `MIN` to it to get the exact number in range.

Formula will be `MIN + (MAX-MIN)*value`

where  `value` is range in between 0-1;
       `MIN` is number mapped to 0;
       `MAX` is number mapped to 1;